# Is PushbackInputStream an alternative for making InputStream consumable repeatedly?

Tags: java, inputstream

As understood, InputStream once consumed, cannot be reused/ re-read back, as it would not have any content.

But, using PushbackInputStream, we could unread the bytes read back into the inputstream.

Can we use PushbackInputStream safely to make InputStream consumable repeatedly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, within its pushback limit, and so is `BufferedInputStream` with the `mark()` and `reset()` features and an adequate buffer, but if you have a solution that involves re-reading input, you  are designing it wrong. A compiler can proceed left to right along the input file without ever backtracking: so can you.